# E-mail não está sendo verdadeiro

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Estou com um problema: estou criando um campo "*esqueceu senha*", onde o usuário digita o e-mail e se ele estiver no banco de dados aparece como *verdadeiro* e redireciona pra página `teste.php`; caso contrário, para a página  `index.php`.

Porém, quando eu clico no botão `recuperar`, vai para a página `index.php` independe se foi verdadeiro ou não. Segue o código:

```php
<?php
session_start();

include_once("../conn/conexao.php");//faz a conexao com o banco de dados
$entrar = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'recuperar', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //aqui se colocar o nome do botão que fara com que entre
if($entrar){
      $ub = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);//aqui se coloca o nome que pegara no banco para fazer o login


    if((!empty($ub)) AND (!empty($ub))){
        $result_usuario = "SELECT * FROM tb_usuario WHERE email='$ub' LIMIT 1";//aqui pegara o usuario no banco de dados
        $resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conexao, $result_usuario) or die (mysqli_error($conexao));
            if($resultado_usuario){
            $row_usuario = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_usuario);
            if($ub== $row_usuario['email']){

                $_SESSION['email'] = $row_usuario['email'];


                if($row_usuario['email']==1){

                header("Location:teste.php");
                }
                else{
                header("Location:index.php");
                }   
                exit; 
            }
            }
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- As 3 meta tags acima *devem* vir em primeiro lugar dentro do `head`; qualquer outro conteúdo deve vir *após* essas tags -->
    <title>Lance Web</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- HTML5 shim e Respond.js para suporte no IE8 de elementos HTML5 e media queries -->
    <!-- ALERTA: Respond.js não funciona se você visualizar uma página file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <style type="text/css">
        /*Aqui deixa a imagem de fundo responsiva*/
        body{ 
            background-color:#0A8AF5;
        }

        /*Aqui se edita o icone de login e senha*/
        #caixaemail{
            padding-left:24px;
            line-height:16px;
            background-position:2px center;
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
            background-image:url(../img/login.png);
        }

        #caixasenha{
            padding-left:24px;
            line-height:16px;
            background-position:2px center;
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
            background-image:url(../img/senha.png);
        }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container" align="center">
        <img src="../img/logomarca.png" class="img-responsive"><br><br><br>
            <form action="" method="post" class="form-signin" role="form">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="caixaemail" placeholder="Digite seu email" required autofocus name="email"><br>
                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" name="recuperar" value="recuperar">Recuperar</button><br>
                </div><!-- fim da div col que centraliza -->
            </form><!-- fim formulario -->
                <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                    <a href="../index.php"><button class="btn btn-lg btn-danger btn-block">Voltar</button></a>
                </div><!-- fim da div col que centraliza -->            
    </div><!-- fim div class container responsiva -->

    <!-- jQuery (obrigatório para plugins JavaScript do Bootstrap) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Inclui todos os plugins compilados (abaixo), ou inclua arquivos separadados se necessário -->
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: a pergunta ficou errada rs

Comment: Kkk concertei..

Comment: resolvi, criei um session do email e comparei com o digitado...

Comment: if($row_usuario['email']==$email){

Comment: Então exclui a pergunta

Comment: @DvD ou então coloca como resposta o que você fez, caso alguém se depare com um problema semelhante a este

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Foi o Ap que resolveu. Veja os comentários acima. Ou ele exclui a pergunta ou então coloca uma resposta.

Comment: @DvD e meu comentário foi uma crítica a seu pedido de exclusão ;-) Ok, eu tentei omiti o agente mas acabei fazendo-nos confusão literária. Poderia muito bem ter sido lida como "responda com o que foi feito", perdão

Comment: Mais sobre o assunto da auto-resposta: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4436/64969

Comment: @pherb bora dar um cheque-mate nesta pergunta? Bota a sua solução numa resposta e depois de uns 15 minutos vc marca ela como certa. Vai ficar show de bola! ;)

Comment: Respondi com a resposta galera, só que só posso marca a resposta com o V de certo depois de 2 dias :/

Comment: @Dvd Eu ia te dizer o que o pherb disse aí em cima. O sistema tem uma regra que se você quiser aceitar a sua própria resposta, deve ser pelo menos dois dias depois de a pergunta ter sido postada. Não sei ao certo qual é a motivação dessa regra, mas ela existe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você inicia um SESSION do e-mail:

```
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
```

E no `if` e `else`, em vez de comparar com `==1` você compara com a variável do `SESSION`:

```
if($row_usuario['email']==$email){ //...
```